# Jquery load() fails in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-load

I know this is a well known problem, however the other posts did not help much. So I have two pages "A" and "B". On page "A" I am refreshing the options in a select field with a jquery ajax load as follows. "changeme" and "replace" are selects.

```
        $("#changeme").change(function(){               
            if($("#changeme :selected").val()>0){
                var resource = "<c:url value="/coursemodules/categoryselect/"/>"+$("#changeme :selected").val()+" option";
                $("#replace").load(resource);
            }else{
                $("#replace").html('<option value="0">UN-CATEGORISED</option>');
            }
        });
```

The URL points to page "B" which has new select-options nested in other template specific div-tags, hence the space and option appended at the end of the url above. Now all this stuff works perfectly except in IE.
The updated select just goes blank with no options on IE. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL being request is valid. Other browsers may try to fix problems in the URL differently and succeed, but

""+$("#changeme :selected").val()+" option";

Looks like it resolves with the JSTL to

```
"/coursemodules/categoryselect/WhateverValue option"
```

The ending looks odd `WhateverValue option` ... Does going to one of these URLs return the expected response?

Comment: Yes it does, this url is only used for ajax and the space option tells jquery to pull out only the option elements on the page. This works as expected in FF and other browsers but IE .... good lord !

Comment: Have you tried using $.get() and then pulling the option elements there. Just as a test to see if it still fails out in IE and if so, help narrow down the problem.